Tensorflow image classification model peaks after second epoch and keeps the same accuracy for the rest of training
I have a simple classification model with 4 different classes, stop, go, right, left traffic hand signals. After the second epoch i get the same accuracy for the rest of the epochs. I have tried using different datasets as well thinking it was a data issue.
def fit_cnn_model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, savedir, num_layers=2,
                  num_filters=64, kernel_size=3, pool_size=2, dropout_rate=0.3, learning_rate=0.0001,
                  n_epochs=10, batch_size=64, verbose=2):

    model = Sequential()
    date_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    for _ in range(num_layers):
        model.add(Conv2D(filters=num_filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
        model.add(BatchNormalization())
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
        model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

    opt = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                        epochs=n_epochs,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
                        verbose=verbose)

    model.summary()

    scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
    print("Loss: {:.2f}".format(scores[0]))
    print("Accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(scores[1] * 100))

    model_path = os.path.join(savedir, 'saved_model_' + date_time + '.h5')
    model.save(model_path)
    print(f"Model saved to {model_path}")

    return model

def load_data(image_folder, label_folder, target_size=(224, 224)):
    # Load and sort dataset
    image_files = os.listdir(image_folder)
    label_files = os.listdir(label_folder)
    image_files.sort()
    label_files.sort()

    images = []
    labels = []

    # Load images and labels
    for img_file in image_files:
        img_path = os.path.join(image_folder, img_file)

        label_file = img_file.replace(".jpg", ".txt").replace(".jpeg", ".txt")
        label_path = os.path.join(label_folder, label_file)

        img = Image.open(img_path).resize(target_size)
        img_array = np.array(img) / 255.0
        images.append(img_array)

        with open(label_path, 'r') as f:
            label_str = f.readline().strip()
            label_dict = {'stop': 0, 'continue': 1, 'left': 2, 'right': 3}
            label = label_dict.get(label_str, -1)
            if label == -1:
                raise ValueError("Unknown label: {}".format(label_str))

        labels.append(label)

    images = np.array(images)
    labels = np.array(labels)
    labels = to_categorical(labels, 4)


    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.2)

    return X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test


I have tried slightly tweaking the learning rate, drop out, layers, and filters. Also used a different proven dataset.

The issue you're facing where the accuracy stagnates after a few epochs could be due to several factors.Data Preprocessing and Augmentation:
Ensure that your data preprocessing is consistent and appropriate for your dataset. Since your images are resized to (224, 224) and normalized by dividing by 255, make sure this preprocessing step is correctly applied to both training and testing datasets.

Experiment with different learning rates and optimizers. A too high or too low learning rate can affect the training process. Consider using learning rate schedulers or adaptive learning rate techniques (e.g., ReduceLROnPlateau) to dynamically adjust the learning rate during training based on validation metrics.
Implement early stopping with a patience parameter to prevent overfitting and to stop training when validation performance stops improving. This can help you save time and prevent unnecessary epochs.
